# If final variable is initialized in parameterized constructor dynamically, then it breaks final rule

Tags: java, initialization, final, parameterized-constructor

If final variable is initialized in parameterized constructor and data is assigned through constructor args then final value seems to be changing here for every object.

```java
public class Test {
  final int k;
  Test(int i){ this.k=i;}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
    Test t= new Test(i);
    System.out.println(t.k);}
  }
}
```

Is the final variable not changable at instance level alone or across all instance it should be constant.?

Comment: you're creating separate instances of object, of course each of them have their own final variable

Comment: to get error you can add `t.k = 10;` before `println` and compiler will prevent you

Comment: @Ilya Bursov - So for each instance final variable can have different value, which is not changable once initialized.

Comment: yes, though you can have static final variable, this variable is the same for all instances, such variable cannot be set via constructor of course

Answer (score 0):

The final variable is assigned to the instance.
If you create multiple instances of the Test class, they will have their own version of the final variable.
If the final variable is static, it will be only be set once for all the instances.

Comment: So Static final variable should be initialized whenever declared. If it is not initialized, then will get compilation error or default value will be set automatically?

Comment: That's right. If you had a final variable, it can exist without initialisation, but that must be instantied through the class's only constructor. If you have a static final variable, that must be declared as soon as it exists. 

class Test{
final String x;
Test(String arg){
this.x=arg;
}
}

^ is ok, but if the String x was static, it would not compile unless you instantiate it directly (static final String x = "hi";)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are creating five separate instances of `Test` and each one has its own instance variable `k`. To see that these are distinct, you can modify your code to something like this:

```
public class Test {
  final int k;
  Test(int i){ this.k=i;}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test[] tests = new Test[5];
    for(int i=0; i<tests.length; i++){
        tests[i] = new Test(i+1);
    }
    for (Test t : tests) { 
        System.out.println(t.k);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5